# get checkbox state when onChange is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm playing in angular and bootstrap.
The question is very trivial.
I have input element in my html

```
  <label><input  (change)="callFilt()"  type="checkbox" 
    value="">{{item.name}}</label>
```

I want to get state of checkbox in my callFilt method.I see that it's possible via ng-model,but I dont want to use any other directives here,is there way to send state of the checkbox?

Neither I want to set id of checkbox and get state via ID in my js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variabile reference  in your markup using the sintax #myInputVariabile and pass it to the function callFilt(checkInput).
something like:

```
<label><input  (change)="callFilt(checkInput)"
```

#checkInput type="checkbox" value="">{{item.name}}

```
   callFilt(element) {
    console.log(element.checked)
  }
```

Comment: yees that works.How do you think,is it a good approach? can there be any issues?

Comment: hostely I would have used ngModel for the simple reason we want to decouple as much as we can view and business logic, some exception can be done in structural directive, but this is a different story.
Do you have any particular reason why you do not want to use ngModel ?

Comment: anyway I do not see any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value buy putting this inside method

```
<label><input  (change)="callFilt(this)"  type="checkbox" 
    value="">{{item.name}}</label>
```

.Now in function

```
 callFilt(e) {
    console.log(e.checked); // or 
    console.log(e.value); //depending input type
  }
```

Comment: Can you check using this in method. for example    this.checked

Comment: I tried as well this approach getting undefined, it looks that does not work as the usual pattern we  use in vanilla JS

Comment: so, practically if we send "this" we are point to the component logic in the typescript file and not to the current element where the event (in this case onchange) was triggered.

you can test as:

 <label><input  (change)="callFilt(checkInput, this)" #checkInput type="checkbox" 
            value="">HOLA</label> 

 callFilt(element,_this) {
    console.log(element.checked)
    console.log(_this)
  }